# AutoCompleteTextView suggestions overlap Android status bar. How to fix?

Tags: android, user-interface, layout, autocomplete

I use AutoCompleteTextView with custom adapter and filter on Android 5.0

Here are screen-shots:

With suggestions:

[image]

Without suggestions:

[image]

This is Xml layout for fragment, without toolbar:

```
<FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
                android:text="Name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"/>

        <TextView
                android:text="Artist name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/artist_name"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: You can set the drop down height. Currently its wrapping the whole content

Answer (score 0):

Use android:fitsSystemWindow="true" in your parent viewgroup.